# Multichannel soundeffects / different perspectives

Tags: sound-effects, sound, library-sound-effects, sound-library

I recently came across some independent sound library publishers offering "multichannel WAV files" for different mic perspectives of the same sound.

Those are not traditional multichannel files (as in stereo or surround) but rather an option to give the editors using the sounds a few options to select from per soundeffect.

I am curious how those files are created (on osx) and how people are using them in their daily sound editing jobs.

They will be split into seperate track when imported in the DAW i suppose? 
And then people mute the layers they dont want?
Or how would one use those multichannel sounds?

Thanks for any hints on this subject!

D.

Answer (score 1):

It´s flexible : if you need a gunshot from 1m away, you got it, and 200 m away you got it too ... Very useful for battle scenes for exemple : i quickly edit all the mics In parallel, and then mute and balance them to Sound close or distant. So yes it comes up With a very large session In your DAW ;-)